# Calculating non-dielectric reflectance without using complex numbers

Tags: visible-light, reflection, complex-numbers

I need a to calculate the fresnel reflection ratio of a non dielectric material given the incident angle, the refractive indexes of the incident and interfacing materials and the extinction coefficient of the interfacing material. I need to to this without directly using complex numbers, due to limitations of the software i am using.

I do not have a physics background, but here is what i have been able to figure out so far.

given

incident angle θi in radians,
incident IOR n1,
interfacing IOR n2
and interfacing extinction coefficient k

I calculate the transmissive angle using snells law

$\theta_{t} = asin(\frac{n_{1}\cdot sin( \theta_{i})}{n_{2}})$

Then using the fresnel equations I calculate the effective reflectance

$R_{p} = (\frac{sin(\theta_{i}) - sin(\theta_{t})}{sin(\theta_{i}) + sin(\theta_{t})})^{2}$

$R_{s} = (\frac{tan(\theta_{i}) - tan(\theta_{t})}{tan(\theta_{i}) + tan(\theta_{t})})^{2}$

$R_{eff} = \frac{R_{p}+R_{s}}{2}$

this gives me this graph for a air to glass interface which looks correct
[image: Interface Graph]

this works for dielectric materials that have a neglectable extinction coefficient, but for metals i need to extend the formulas i have. all the reference i can find extends the IOR with an imaginary component that handles the extinction coefficient, the problem is the graphic software im using does not allow complex numbers, so i need some way to extend the formulas i have using real numbers only.

the only reference i was able to find is this page https://seblagarde.wordpress.com/2013/04/29/memo-on-fresnel-equations/#more-1921
the code on that page is avoiding the use of complex numbers but i am unable to make heads or tails of what is actually happening here.

any help intergrating the extinction coefficient into the existing formulas above is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: thanks, updated that

Comment: I was about to write that you pose an interesting challenge.  Then I looked at the site you found.  It looks like the answer might be in that rather nice website you quote, the four equations immediately after the heading "Fresnel Equations in practice".  I don't see any mention of phase.  I'll admit that I looked at that site only briefly.